# Child view controller elements not visible in delegate call back method

Tags: ios, objective-c

this is my scenario, I have a Child view controller `B` to view controller `A` and in `B`, I am making a NSURLSession call and dispatches asynchronously to main thread on response

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    // calls the call back delegate method
   [self.delegate cllBackMethod];

    }
```

In view controller B i am setting the delegate as self and defining this call back method as

```
-(void) callBackMethod{
   NSLog(@"%@",self.headerLabel);
   self.headerLabel.hidden=YES;
}
```

If I make `B` as a child view controller to `A` , its logging (null) and I am not able to access B elements. But If i present `B` from `A` instead of making it as a child view controller i am able to access these elements and is able to modify.

Why is this happening? and how can I fix this?

Comment: My guess would be that the view hasn't finished loading when the asynchronous call has completed in some cases. Can you provide more of the sample code?

Comment: the view is completely loaded, button action on B is making this network call